# Elementary Real Analysis - Let me know if I'm on the right track

Tags: real-analysis, functions, limits

So I'm guessing this is a pretty simple example for this topic but I just want to check myself as I'm new to this analysis area and not sure that what I'm saying is mathematically sound..

The question is show that $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1} =1$.

So we must show as $x \to -\infty$, $\left|\tfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}  -1\right| < \epsilon$.

My attempt is :

\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}  -1\right| &=\left|\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}  - \dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2-1} \right| \\\\
&=\left|\dfrac{(x^2+1)-(x^2-1)}{x^2-1} \right| \\\\
&=\left|\dfrac{x^2-x^2+1+1}{x^2-1}\right| \\\\
&=\left|\dfrac{2}{x^2-1}\right| < \left|\dfrac{2}{x^2-4}\right| = \left|\dfrac{2}{(x+2)(x-2)}\right| \\
\end{align*}

Now is where I'm not 100 percent sure that what I'm doing is right, can we then say that as $x$ approaches negative infinity, $(x+2)$ and $(x-2)$ become very large and negative, and therefore $2/(x+2)(x-2)$ becomes smaller and smaller and so, for any $\epsilon>0$,

$$\epsilon > \left|\dfrac{2}{(x+2)(x-2)}\right| > \left|\dfrac{2}{x^2-1}\right| = \left|\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}  -1\right|$$   thus proving the original problem ... is this ok/rigorous?

please dont be too hard on me I'm really still just trying to grasp the ideas and understand exactly what we are 'allowed' to do .. thanks for any help

Comment: What you have to show is that **for a fixed $\epsilon>0$**, there exists a $x_0$ such that whenever $x\leq x_0$ the relation $\left|\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1} -1\right|<\epsilon$ holds, and this has to be true **for all $\epsilon>0$**.

Comment: And so, if you want to be rigorous, you have to fix $\epsilon>0$, and find a $x_0$ (which might depend on $\epsilon$)

Comment: Ronald, welcome to math.SE, and let me express my appreciation that you are explaining what you've thought about your question so far - it is far more satisfying for people to help someone who has tried to do it themselves first! Keep it up!

Comment: @MTurgeon .. Thanks for that, I get what you mean but for some reason the only x0 i can find fits x>=x0.. which makes no sense but probably a silly mistake from rushing @ZevChonoles♦ yeah ive been loving this site since I found it .. only now have i ever actually make a post.. I get what you mean aswell, it must be seriously frustrating trying to help someone when you dont know what they do/dont understand

Comment: @Ronald Well, you are pretty close. At some point, you have figured out that $\left|\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}-1\right|=\frac{2}{|x^2-1|}$, and so you want $x$ such that $|x^2-1|>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$. I leave you the rest.

Comment: @MTurgeon aaaaaah you are a champion !

Comment: @Ronald I am glad I could be useful! If you wish, you can post your solution one it is complete and accept it. This way, your question won't go unanswered.

Comment: @MTurgeon ok wait you are still a champion, but one quick thing (just clarification).. so at the step x^2 > 2/ϵ-1 , the logical next step is x > sqrt(2/ϵ-1), but x is approaching negative infinity and so we want it to be in the form x<=f(ϵ)... so can we say that due to the nature of the square(always positive) that x > sqrt(2/ϵ-1) OR x < -sqrt(2/ϵ-1) ??

Comment: @Ronald When you take the square root, you have to keep the absolute value: $$x^2>2/\epsilon-1 \Rightarrow |x|>\sqrt{2/\epsilon -1}.$$

Comment: @MTurgeon thanks so much for all your help .. i posted an answer so maybe someone else can oneday can use it to help them understand too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\epsilon>0$, then

$$\begin{align*} \left|\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1} - 1\right| < \epsilon
&\Rightarrow \left|\frac{2}{x^2-1}\right| < \epsilon \\
&\Rightarrow \left|\frac{x^2-1}{2}\right| > 1/\epsilon \\
&\Rightarrow |x^2-1| > \frac{2}{\epsilon}. \end{align*}
$$

when $x^2-1 > 0$, $x^2>1 $, $|x| > 1$,

so, $(x^2-1)>2/\epsilon$ .... (when $|x|>1$)

$x^2 > 2/\epsilon+1$

$|x| > \sqrt{2/\epsilon+1}$

therefore :

Given any $\epsilon > 0 $, $\left|\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1} - 1\right| < \epsilon$

when $|x| > \sqrt{2/ϵ+1}$.

ta da !

references : M Turgeon that king !